# SWI-Prolog - when will a predicate loaded from source file take effect?

Tags: prolog

In SWI-Prolog, I want to load differente files based on input in a predicate, and use rules defines in this file in this predicate, but it didn't work. I wonder if there's a way to load file that rules in this file could take effect immediately.

The thing I want to achieve is like:

`rule.pl`:

```
classify(X,Y):-X('1'),Y('2').
```

`main.pl`:

```
RuleFile('rule')
initClassify(X,Y):-load_files(RuleFile),classify(X,Y).
```

When I call `initClassify/2`, it complained that `classify/2` undefined procedure.

Comment: When you load a file, it will warn about any predicates it sees called without having seen the definition, so it will warn about `classify/2` because it hasn't seen the definition when it parses the file. I suspect you have other errors because `RuleFile('rule')` is not valid syntax (and neither is `X('1')`) which you need to fix first. (Uppercase is reserved for variables in Prolog.)

Comment: have you seen [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=load_files/2) or [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=use_module/2) ?